# looping through set of elements in jquery

Tags: jquery, iteration, css-selectors

`$('form td .hint p')` this jquery selector returns back a list `[p,p,p,p,p,p]`.

I would like to know what's the best way to loop through each of those, check their css values, and do something if the css value = something I want.

I have this function to show and hide a tooltip, but I only want one tooltip to be shown at a time. While doing mouseover and mouseout works, it's buggy because currently I'm using parent(), next(), and child(), to find the right element, and jquery instantaneously inserts a div wrapping around the element I'm showing and hiding. So basically I'm trying to force all other p elements that have display:block to hide every time mouseover occurs.

Currently doing this:

```
target = $('form td .hint p');
target[0].css('display') gives an error.

target.css('display') seems to only return the css of the first one.
```

Comment: Have you looked at the variety of jQuery plugins that offer tooltip functionality? docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip for instance?

Answer (score 14):

Use [`each()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.each):

```
var displays = '';
$("p").each(function(i, val) {
  displays += "Paragraph " + i + ": " + $(this).css("display") + "\n";
});
alert(displays);
```

The reason this fails:

```
var target = $("p");
var display = target[0].css("display");
```

is that `target[0]` is *not* a jQuery object. You could do this:

```
var display = $(target[0]).css("display");
```

Also, if you read the documentation for [`css()`](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/css#name):

> Return a style property on the first
>   matched element.

Two other points worth mentioning.

Firstly, I wouldn't advise doing a tooltip yourself. Get one of the many plugins for this. I've used [this one](http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/) previously and it did the job.

Secondly, if you're checking CSS display values, there may be a shortcut worth using. For instance, you could do this:

```
$("p").each(function() {
  if ($(this).css("display") == "none") {
    $(this).addClass("blah");
  }
});
```

but you can also use the [`:hidden`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/hidden) and [`:visible`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/visible) selectors, so:

```
$("p:hidden").addClass("blah");
```

Checking values of `css()` calls is largely unreliable as you're only checking inline styles and not stylesheet values.

Comment: Hey, actually I just figured out using the :visible selector did the trick. Thanks for the response though, because I need the each() function for something else. Thanks.